# Freemarker template for gradle build files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, freemarker

Hi I'm trying to make a build.gradle file from a freemarker template and I'm running in to small problem both Freemarker and de gradle DSL support `${someString}`

So somewhere in the gradle script I have field/variable definition.

For instance I define a String like below:

`def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()`

And would use that somewhere else in the gradle file like so:

`filename = "new-archive-${gitSha}.jar"`

But then when I generate the gradle file with Freemarker I get the error gitSha is null or not defined in the data-model. Is there a way to make a distinction between `${gitSha}` which is for the gradle DSL and the other `${someStrings}` which are part of the Freemarker template?

Answer (score 0):

In principle the correct solution would be to use something else instead of `${}` in some of the two languages (let's say, `@{}`). But at least in Freemarker that's not configurable. But it could be emulated (kind of...), if you write a custom `TempalateLoader` that just wraps another `TemplateLoader`, but filters the `Reader` so that `@{`-s are replaced with `${`-s, and `${` are replaced with `@{`. And then, the same transformation has to be applied to the `Writer` where Freemarker writes its output into, so the `@{` in the output are replaced with `${`-s. (I hope BTW that sooner or later Freemarker will have a configurable interpolation syntax, because this issue with `${` comes up quite often, but that's the future...)

Comment: okay so there is no simple way to fix this other then writing a custom templateloader.